# JSON error that I can't seem to find

Tags: graphics-card

Below is my configuration file for my Gigabyte R9 280x Graphic cards, used in a mining rig. For some reason I keep getting an error:

> [2013-12-25 07:49:10] ./cgminer: --config: JSON decode of file 'r9_280.conf' failed
>    string or '}' expected near ''

I’ve gone through the file, but I can’t seem to find the error… all the parenthesis are there!

Thank you for your help!

```
{
    "pools" :
        [
            {
            "url" : "http://ltc-eu.give-me-coins.com:3333",
            "user" : "xxxx.1",
            "pass" : "xxxx"
            }
        ],
    "intensity" :       "13",
    "vectors" :         "1",
    "worksize" :        "256",
    "kernel" :          "scrypt",
    "lookup-gap" :      "0",
    "thread-concurrency" : "8192",
    "shaders" :         "2048",
    "gpu-engine" :      "1020",
    "gpu-fan" :         "0-100",
    "gpu-memclock" :    "1500",
    "gpu-memdiff" :     "0",
    "gpu-powertune" :   "0",
    "gpu-vddc" :        "0.000",
    "temp-cutoff" :     "95",
    "temp-overheat" :   "85",
    "temp-target" :     "78",
    "api-mcast-port" :  "4028",
    "api-port" :        "4028",
    "auto-fan" :        true,
    "expiry" :          "120",
    "gpu-dyninterval" : "7",
    "gpu-platform" :    "0",
    "gpu-threads" :     "2",
    "hotplug" :         "5",
    "log" :             "5",
    "no-pool-disable" : true,
    "queue" :           "1",
    "scan-time" :       "60",
    "scrypt" :          true,
    "temp-hysteresis" : "3",
    "shares" :          "0",
    "kernel-path" :     "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

Comment: Was it working before? Have you created the file from scratch or using some template/example file?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON block is valid, I think your problem lies elsewhere. Maybe `cgminer` is expecting one of the arguments to be of a type other than string?